# Command to display an arbitrary message if a particular file exists

Tags: command-line

Is there a command to display message “Yes” if a particular file exists? No need to give functionality if the file does not exist.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use this simple Bash one-liner:

```
if [ -e FILENAME ] ; then echo Yes ; fi
```

The `-e` check evaluates to true if `FILENAME` exists, no matter what it is (file, directory, link, device, ...).

If you only want to check regular files, use `-f` instead, as *@Arronical* said.

Comment: `[ -e FILENAME ] && echo Yes`

Comment: @ZebMcCorkle Correct, that works too. You might post that as separate answer.

Comment: If `FILENAME` is a variable expansion, or contains any special characters, then don't forget to quote it.  e.g. in a script, `[ -e "$1" ] && echo Yes`.

Comment: @PeterCordes if you're using bash you can use `[[` and `]]` instead of quoting the variable.

Comment: @Holloway: yup, but sometimes you need to write portable scripts that only require POSIX sh.  That's why I gave a safe version of this instead of downvoting it and upvoting the bash answer.  Also note that it's not a problem to quote expansions inside `[[ ]]`, always quoting is a good habit for beginners that don't remember the special rules for  inside the `[[ ]]` operator, or for arithmetic contexts.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -f $1 ]]; then
    echo "Yes"
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Save it as `file-exists.sh`. Then, in the Terminal, type `chmod +x file-exists.sh`.

Use it like: `./file-exists.sh FILE` where you replace `FILE` with the file you want to check, for example:

```
./file-exists.sh file.txt
```

If `file.txt` exists, `Yes` will be printed to the Terminal, and the program will exit with status 0 (success). If the file does not exist, nothing will be printed and the program will exit with status 1 (failure).

If you're curious why I included the `exit` command, read on...

---

### What's up with the `exit` command?

`exit` causes normal process termination. What this means is, basically: it stops the script. It accepts an optional (numerical) parameter that will be the exit status of the script that called it.

This exit status enables your other scripts to use your `file-exists` script and is their way of knowing the file exists or not.

A simple example that puts this to use is this script (save it as `file-exists-cli.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter a filename and I will tell you if it exists or not: "
read FILE
# Run `file-exists.sh` but discard any output because we don't need it in this example
./file-exists.sh $FILE &>> /dev/null
# #? is a special variable that holds the exit status of the previous command
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
    echo "$FILE exists"
else
    echo "$FILE does not exist"
fi
```

Do the usual `chmod +x file-exists-cli.sh` and then run it: `./file-exists-cli.sh`. You'll see something like this:

**File exists (`exit 0`):**

```
➜  ~ ./file-exists-cli.sh 
Enter a filename and I will tell you if it exists or not: 
booleans.py
booleans.py exists
```

**File does not exist (`exit 1`):**

```
➜  ~ ./file-exists-cli.sh
Enter a filename and I will tell you if it exists or not: 
asdf
asdf does not exist
```

Comment: Good, but Thou shalt quote variable references like `"$1"`. If it has white space in it, it will break without quotes and other bad things can happen.

Answer (score 9):

In the bash shell on the command line.

```
if [[ -f /path/to/file ]]; then echo "Yes"; fi
```

This uses the bash conditional operator `-f`, and is checking whether the file exists and is a regular file. If you want to test for any files including directories and links then use `-e`.

[This is a great resource for bash conditionals.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals)

Comment: Why the double braces?

Comment: I'm not a fan of `test` in it's original format, I know it's overkill, but it's habit of mine.

Comment: @ByteCommander: double braces are just generally better than single braces. They're part of the shell syntax (instead of invoking the `[` command, which usually calls a builtin.) They correct inconsistencies and dumb behaviors of the single brace version. The [ builtin remains for compatibility, but I don't see any good reason to use it in new bash code. (If you need to write POSIX-compliant scripts that can run on ancient shells or something, that's different.)

Comment: @kundor: Mostly agreed, though, to be fair, "`[` usually calls a builtin" is dubious. `type -a [` for me lists "shell builtin", then "`/usr/bin/[`."

Comment: @wchargin: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're getting at. Your `type` results seem to corroborate what I said, no?

Answer (score 5):

The shortest command for doing what you want is:

```
test -e FILENAME && echo Yes
```

`test -e` will test whether the name given exists in the file system. (You can use `test -f` to restrict to regular files only. See `man test` for more.)

If the condition given evaluates to true, then `test` returns a successful exit status (otherwise it returns a failure status). We combine the two commands using `&&`, which means "execute the next command if the previous command exited with a success status". The next command simply prints `Yes` on standard output; in the case of an interactive shell, on the terminal.

This avoids the additional textual material of an `if` statement, yet gives the same result. Using `&&` (or its opposite, `||`) to tie commands together works well when only a single command is involved. If you want to do more than execute a single command in response to a single command's exit status, then using the `if` syntax quickly becomes much more readable.

As already pointed out in other answers, the equivalent `if` style construct would be:

```
if test -e FILENAME; then echo Yes; fi
```

or alternatively:

```
if test -e FILENAME
then
    echo Yes
fi
```

For these purposes, `[` and `test` are equivalent, except that `[` demands a terminating `]`.

Answer (score 4):

To skin this type of question there's multiple ways, and here's another one : use `find` command with `-exec` flag . The path to file can be split into two parts `find /etc` which sets directory and `-name FILENAME` which specifies filename (duh!) . `-maxdepth` will keep `find` working with `/etc` directory only and won't descend into subdirectories

```
adminx@L455D:~$ find /etc -maxdepth 1  -name passwd -exec printf "YES\n" \;
YES
adminx@L455D:~$ find /etc -maxdepth 1  -name passwd1 -exec printf "YES\n" \;
adminx@L455D:~$
```

Another way , via `stat` :

```
adminx@L455D:~$ stat /etc/passwd1 &>/dev/null && echo YES
adminx@L455D:~$ stat /etc/passwd &>/dev/null && echo YES
YES
```

And alternatively  via python :

```
>>> import os
>>> if os.stat('/etc/passwd'): 
...    print 'YES'
... 
YES
>>> if os.stat('/etc/passwd1'): 
...    print 'YES'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/passwd1'
```

Or a short command line alternative :

```
 python -c "from os.path import exists; print 'Yes' if exists('/etc/fstab') else '' "
```